# Maven bind plugin command to lifecycle

Tags: maven

My project use sonar plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Just wonder if possible that if any configuration makes when I run command:

```
mvn clean install
```

would automatically run the `mvn sonar:sonar` comand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a plugin to a phase by using `executions`:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>sonar</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

So your complete plugin config looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sonar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Within the `phase` tag, choose the appropriate phase. You can learn more about the Maven lifecycle [in the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: would the 'validate' goal be more appropriate than 'install'?

Comment: @jbruni yes, propably `validate` would be more appropriate, since Sonar checks if your project is valid.